# Assume role from aws cli with SAML

Tags: amazon-web-services, saml-2.0, aws-cli, amazon-iam, opensaml

I'm trying to generate aws credentials using `aws sts assume-role-with-saml` from this [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/aws-cli-call-store-saml-credentials/)

However I'm getting errors and I don't really understand, the flow. Normally I've a main account **ACCOUNT_A** where she **SAML_PROVIDER** resides and from which I switch role to the account **ACCOUNT_B**. So from my understand the syntax should look like :

`aws sts assume-role-with-saml --role-arn arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_B:role/IAM_ROLE --principal-arn arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_A:saml-provider/SAML_PROVIDER --saml-assertion BASE64_ENCODED_RESPONSE`

But when I try the above way I get the error :

> An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the
>   AssumeRoleWithSAML operation: Principal exists outside the account of
>   the Role being assumed

Then if try this way :

`aws sts assume-role-with-saml --role-arn arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_B:role/IAM_ROLE --principal-arn arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_B:saml-provider/SAML_PROVIDER --saml-assertion BASE64_ENCODED_RESPONSE`

I get error:

> An error occurred (InvalidIdentityToken) when calling the
>   AssumeRoleWithSAML operation: Specified provider doesn't exist
>   (Service: AWSOpenIdDiscoveryService; Status Code: 400; Error Code:
>   AuthSamlManifestNotFoundException; Request ID:
>   3565c77a-44b6-11e9-a384-b1f45948a767)

I think the documentation is not clear on the functional aspect, and there is not really clear example on google... So my questions are:

- what account numbers should I use at these two place in the syntax?
- Do I need to create a SAML IDP in the ACCOUNT_B account?

Comment: Well, I've dissected the request, and it seems like I should create a SAML idp in ACCOUNT_B

I'll do this way and test

Answer (score 1):

in fact I think the SAML part confused me, there’s nothing to create in the other account **(ACCOUNT_B)**, if that it would mean that you bypass the bounce account **(ACCOUNT_A)**, and it loses its interest and its security purpose. But you have to use the **SAML idp** present on **ACCOUNT_A** to generate credentials that will then allow to switch from A to B, exactly as it works without delegation